# How to create table in FPDF using php?

Tags: php, html, pdf, fpdf

I am trying to create a PDF file using PHP.

My problem is that I want to create a table and I'm not sure how to.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Yes, my suggestion is to read the fine documentation.

Comment: What do you mean? i am asking for how to create table in fpdf. is that a stupied question?

Comment: It is not a stupid question but it is much too broad for StackOverflow. The [docs](http://www.fpdf.org/en/script/script3.php) show you how to make tables.

Comment: @MaherMahmoud Welcome to stackoverflow.  If you need help, you should demonstrate what you've tried and people will be more than happy to help you get past your blocking issue.  This may help you get started here: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively look at [tutorial 6](http://www.fpdf.org/en/tutorial/tuto6.htm)

```
$pdf->WriteHTML($html);
```

You can just write your table and output it like that.

Although I would recommend [TCPDF](http://www.tcpdf.org/) as its a bit more versatile

Answer (score 1):

```
int PDF_add_table_cell ( resource $pdfdoc , int $table , int $column ,
                         int $row , string $text , string $optlist )
```

Adds a cell to a new or existing table.

More info on PDF functions can be found here:
http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdf.php

---

If you want to use FPDF here is an example taken from [FPDF.org](http://www.fpdf.org/en/script/script3.php)

```
<?php
require('fpdf.php');    
class PDF_MC_Table extends FPDF {
 var $widths;
 var $aligns;

 function SetWidths($w){
    //Set the array of column widths
    $this->widths=$w;
 }

 function SetAligns($a){
    //Set the array of column alignments
    $this->aligns=$a;
 }

 function Row($data){
    //Calculate the height of the row
    $nb=0;
    for($i=0;$i<count($data);$i++)
        $nb=max($nb,$this->NbLines($this->widths[$i],$data[$i]));
    $h=5*$nb;
    //Issue a page break first if needed
    $this->CheckPageBreak($h);
    //Draw the cells of the row
    for($i=0;$i<count($data);$i++){
        $w=$this->widths[$i];
        $a=isset($this->aligns[$i]) ? $this->aligns[$i] : 'L';
        //Save the current position
        $x=$this->GetX();
        $y=$this->GetY();
        //Draw the border
        $this->Rect($x,$y,$w,$h);
        //Print the text
        $this->MultiCell($w,5,$data[$i],0,$a);
        //Put the position to the right of the cell
        $this->SetXY($x+$w,$y);
    }
    //Go to the next line
    $this->Ln($h);
 }

 function CheckPageBreak($h){
    //If the height h would cause an overflow, add a new page immediately
    if($this->GetY()+$h>$this->PageBreakTrigger)
        $this->AddPage($this->CurOrientation);
 }

 function NbLines($w,$txt){
    //Computes the number of lines a MultiCell of width w will take
    $cw=&$this->CurrentFont['cw'];
    if($w==0)
        $w=$this->w-$this->rMargin-$this->x;
    $wmax=($w-2*$this->cMargin)*1000/$this->FontSize;
    $s=str_replace("\r",'',$txt);
    $nb=strlen($s);
    if($nb>0 and $s[$nb-1]=="\n")
        $nb--;
    $sep=-1;
    $i=0;
    $j=0;
    $l=0;
    $nl=1;
    while($i<$nb){
        $c=$s[$i];
        if($c=="\n"){
            $i++;
            $sep=-1;
            $j=$i;
            $l=0;
            $nl++;
            continue;
        }
        if($c==' ')
            $sep=$i;
        $l+=$cw[$c];
        if($l>$wmax){
            if($sep==-1){
                if($i==$j)
                    $i++;
            } else
                $i=$sep+1;
            $sep=-1;
            $j=$i;
            $l=0;
            $nl++;
        } else
            $i++;
    }
    return $nl;
 }
}
?>
```